# PrintPreviewControl will not switch to landscape vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

When I set the `PrintDocument` object to landscape through `PrintPage` method
`e.PageSettings.landscape=True`. If I send it to the printer it works fine. 
But on the `PrintPreviewControl` it remains in portrait. I can't find a way to change the page size or orientation directly in the `PrintPreviewControl`. I have tried to set `PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true` and this does not help either.

```
Private Sub pDocument_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pDocument.PrintPage

        Select Case QueryRep.ReportStyle ' only have one report style, reserved for custom reporting for each customer.

            Case 0 ' standard report format
                StandardReport(e)

        End Select

        ' isLandscape is a public variable set by the standardReport() sub
        e.PageSettings.Landscape = isLandscape

    End Sub
```

Comment: more information, it works if i set to landscape before i set ppcontrol.document=pdocument but if it is set after this it will not adjust. Is there a way to refresh the ppcontrol ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around the issue. once the print object is linked to the preview control, you cannot change width or height or other page properties. The property will change but the print preview control will not respond to them. I tried to refresh the control many different ways and nothing worked. But if you send it to the printer you can change these settings during the print process and the printer will respond. My workaround was not the best solution but the only one i could find. Was to create a new print object and a new print preview control then get the information i needed from this. then destroy this control, and configure the new print object then link it to the preview control. If someone has a better way let me know.